# Xcode 12 won't let me use lower iOS versions

Tags: swift, xcode, simulator

I recently got the M1 MacBook and it automatically updates you to Xcode 12 and I can't use any simulators below iOS 14.Is there a way around this?

Note: Yes I have downloaded the older simulators

Comment: Did you download the other simulators?

Comment: yes I have downloaded them

Comment: same here, did you find a way to add the downloaded lower version simulator?

Comment: @Ian For me the issue is 'sort of' resolved by when you switch to iOS 14 simulators you need to go to exclude architectures and put in "arm64" but for lower iOS versions if you are getting the error about the pod framework and it being (x86_64 or arm64) you will just need to run a clean, wait for it to complete and you should be able to run your project. Only problem I found with this still is it crashing my Quick/Nimble framework on lower iOS versions. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve the different iOS version problems on the M1. For iOS 14 and up, go to `Excluded Architectures` in `Build Settings` and add `arm64`. For lower iOS versions just clean and build and it should work. Only problem I still run into is my Quick/Nimble framework crashing through the lower iOS versions.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking on your simulator icon to the right of `Run` button. At the bottom of popped up list you'll find `Download Simulators`. Go there and pick the one you want.

Comment: @SReddy, is your project's target less or equal the iOS version you're trying to run with?

Comment: @SReddy, like if you have iOS 14 as project's target, there won't be shown any older simulators